# Teradata: Cursor for Resultset of Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I created a stored procedure, which is calling another stored procedure. This called procedure returns one resultset ("DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1").

My question is: how can I access the resultset inside my stored procedure?
I tried to use a cursor, but it seems like a cursor can only access resultsets of a select statement.
Is there another way to retrieve the data from the resultset?

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE XY
BEGIN
...
  CALL ABC; /* how to access the resultset of ABC? */
..
END
```

Comment: Maybe the first proc could insert into a global temporary table, and second proc read from it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the "inner" procedure, because it's a stored procedure from teradata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use standard SQL ALLOCATE. Something like this:

```
,,,
CALL ABC;
/* Get access to (first) result set */
ALLOCATE abc_results CURSOR FOR PROCEDURE ABC;
FETCH FIRST FROM abc_results INTO x, y, z;
...
WHILE ... DO
  FETCH NEXT FROM abc_results INTO x, y, z;
  ...
END WHILE;
CLOSE abc_results;
...
```